# Check links on external websites?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, webrat

I need to check reciprocal links on external websites - are the best options webrat or capybara in a Rails app? Or something else?

Users will submit the URL of the page where the link back to us has been placed, so we don't need a crawl of the whole site, just the page that is submitted.

Comment: Do you want to process JS as well?

Comment: Hi David, no, just HTML links.

Comment: Then you don't need Webrat or Capybara (which are intended for full-stack Rails **testing**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For typical HTML parsing, use Nokogiri.